# Remove Prefixes From a String

Tags: python

What's a cute way to do this in python?

Say we have a list of strings:

```
clean_be
clean_be_al
clean_fish_po
clean_po
```

and we want the output to be:

```
be
be_al
fish_po
po
```

Comment: `[i.lstrip("clean_") for i in string_list]`, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i did because of no efforts done or shown by you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach which will work for all scenarios:

```
import re
data = ['clean_be',
'clean_be_al',
'clean_fish_po',
'clean_po', 'clean_a', 'clean_clean', 'clean_clean_1']
for item in data:
    item = re.sub('^clean_', '', item)
    print (item)
```

Output:

```
be
be_al
fish_po
po
a
clean
clean_1
```

Comment: But what if the test case is `clean_clean_al`. It will return only `al` which is wrong as the user asked to remove only first substring

Comment: Nice catch as I missed the work 'prefix', updated the code now, please check

Comment: This could be the accepted question, it's robust in all cases. The currently accepted one is not as good as this answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution that works with any prefix:

```
prefix = 'clean_'
result = [s[len(prefix):] if s.startswith(prefix) else s for s in lst]
```

Comment: btw riccardo quick thing, if the list has `.csv` at the end of each of them, how do i remove that from them as well?

Comment: @caasswa `s[len(prefix):-4]`. This works only if the '.csv' extension is there for *each* string

Answer (score 1):

You've merely provided minimal information on what you're trying to achieve, but the desired output for the 4 given inputs can be created via the following function:

```
def func(string): 
   return "_".join(string.split("_")[1:])
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you, it was a minimal question!

Comment: @caasswa I did a small mistake in the previous version of my answer, please take note of the change - besides that you're welcome :)

Comment: @caasswa be careful with this solution. It may return the wrong result if you have strings that *do not* start with that prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lstrip` to remove a prefix and `rstrip` to remove a suffix

```
line = "clean_be"
print(line.lstrip("clean_"))
```

**Drawback:**

`lstrip([chars])`

*The [chars] argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.*

Comment: This is very wrong. `'clean_a'.lstrip('clean_')` would return an empty string

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Why does it return an empty string?

Comment: Try it :) it will give you an empty string! Because it removes also the 'a' character after the '_' character

Comment: I've tried it but that isn't really a reason why it's happening

Comment: @RiccardoBucco, it is returning an empty string for test case `clean_a`. Why is it not returning `a`

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG because `lstrip` does not remove a prefix, but all letters of the argument. Try to read the official documentation. Also try this `'clean_hello'.lstrip('nae_lc')`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco it is returning `hello`. So, I guess we shouldn't use `lstrip` in this case

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG exactly, that's why I'm saying this answer is completely wrong!

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I've updated the answer, hopefully it'll prevent `lstrip()` from being used to remove prefixes in the future

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
strlist = ['clean_be','clean_be_al','clean_fish_po','clean_po']

def func(myList:list, start:str):
    ret = []
    for element in myList:
        ret.append(element.lstrip(start))
    return ret

print(func(strlist, 'clean_'))
```

I hope, it was useful, Nohab

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do based on what you have provided.
Apart from the above answers, you can do in this way too:

```
string = 'clean_be_al'
string = string.replace('clean_','',1)
```

This would remove the first occurrence of `clean_` in the string.
Also if the first word is guaranteed to be 'clean', then you can try in this way too:

```
string = 'clean_be_al'
print(string[6:])
```